# JQuery multiple calls reduces performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that if I call the same diagram 20 times, it slows down the diagram 20 times, very strange...? So for each click, the diagrams slows down even more, but before the second click the diagram works very fast. I have created a diagram that just displays some random generated values and show them in x- and y-coordinate diagram (dynamically).

**Is there something I am doing wrong in the JavaScript and JQuery code below? I want the user too only view one diagram at time, without getting slower performance by clicking on the same diagram?**

```
   $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
             var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
             $('.active').removeClass('active');
             $('#table' + row).addClass('active'); 

             if(row == 1){
                $.getScript("diagram1.js", table1()); 

             } else if (row == 2) {
                $.getScript("diagram2.js", function(){}); 
                table2();
             } else if (row == 3) {
                $.getScript("diagram3.js", function(){}); 
                table3();  

        });
```

Here is the list where the user navigates from to view the diagrams individually:

```
<div>
   <ul class="list-group">
   <!--Set this inside a div to individuelly choose-->
   <div id='list_row1' data-row="1"><li class="list-group-item">table1</li></div>
   <div id='list_row2' data-row="2"><li class="list-group-item">table2</li></div>
   <div id='list_row3' data-row="3"><li class="list-group-item">table3</li></div>
   <div id='list_row4' data-row="4"><li class="list-group-item">table4</li></div> 
</div>
```

Each diagram is wrapped around this structure:

```
(function table1(){          
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // table1 code content is taken away to save space in this file on stackoverflow... 
  });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The slowdown probably happens in your external scripts that you are loading multiple times. Instead of using `getScript()`, you should just include the content of those scripts in functions and call the functions.

Comment: I can't see the code in the three files you are calling, so I can't show you.